# Error in Deploying Interactive Map App to ShinyApps.io from RStudio

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

I attempted to convert a series of geospatial maps into an interactive app that can be viewed to save space in a paper. I've been using Shiny to do so, and I've had no problems locally, but I can't seem to get the app to deploy correctly.

Within RStudio, the app deploys successfully without issue, however, when you attempt to view the app, you get the error message, "An error has occurred!
An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification" and when I check the logs, I find

```
Warning: Error in setCurrentTheme: could not find function "setCurrentTheme"
2023-08-24T12:57:17.210444+00:00 shinyapps\[9670162\]:   15: \<Anonymous\>
2023-08-24T12:57:17.215275+00:00 shinyapps\[9670162\]:   13: fn
2023-08-24T12:57:17.219873+00:00 shinyapps\[9670162\]:    8: retry
2023-08-24T12:57:17.224250+00:00 shinyapps\[9670162\]:    7: connect$retryingStartServer
2023-08-24T12:57:17.228735+00:00 shinyapps\[9670162\]:    6: eval
2023-08-24T12:57:17.233657+00:00 shinyapps\[9670162\]:    5: eval
2023-08-24T12:57:17.238031+00:00 shinyapps\[9670162\]:    4: eval
2023-08-24T12:57:17.246391+00:00 shinyapps\[9670162\]:    3: eval
2023-08-24T12:57:17.251223+00:00 shinyapps\[9670162\]:    2: eval.parent
2023-08-24T12:57:17.255758+00:00 shinyapps\[9670162\]     1: local
```

However, nowhere in my code do I call for "setCurrentTheme" and I've made sure to limit the dependencies to only those required for the app.

I have tried moving the app components to a separate directory and made sure only the dependencies absolutely required for the app are loaded. I have also looked over my entire code for "setCurrentTheme" and found nothing. The error remained through every redeployment on each of these fix attempts.

This is the code for my app,

```
# Load necessary libraries
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(rsconnect)
library(sf)

# Define UI
geo_ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Geospatial Distribution of Health Life Expectancy (HLE) and Life Expectancy (LE)"),
  
  # Description
  headerPanel(h3("Interactive visualization of HLE and LE across different regions.")),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      tags$hr(),  # Horizontal line for separation
      
      # Dropdown for outcome selection with descriptive label
      tags$label("Select an outcome:"),
      selectInput("outcome", NULL, choices = names(rename_map)),
      
      tags$br(),  # Break for spacing
      
      # Dropdown for region selection with descriptive label
      tags$label("Select a region:"),
      selectInput("region", NULL, choices = unique(HLE_data$Region)),
      
      tags$hr()  # Horizontal line for separation
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("geospatialPlot", height = "600px")  # Set a fixed height for consistent rendering
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
geo_server <- function(input, output) {
  output$geospatialPlot <- renderPlot({
    HLE_data_region <- HLE_data %>% filter(Region == input$region)
    
    # Use the geospatial plotting code
    geospatial_plot <- ggplot() +
      geom_sf(data = HLE_data_region, aes(geometry = geometry, fill = !!sym(input$outcome)), color = "black", size = 0.1) +
      scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "D") +
      theme_minimal() +
      labs(x = "Longitude", y = "Latitude", title = paste0("Geospatial Distribution of ", rename_map[input$outcome], " in ", input$region)) +
      theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 20), text = element_text(size = 16), legend.position = "bottom")
    
    return(geospatial_plot)
  })
}

#Deploy app locally
#shinyApp(ui = geo_ui, server = geo_server)


# Save ui to ui.R
dump("geo_ui", file = "ui.R")

# Save server to server.R
dump("geo_server", file = "server.R")



# Deploy the app to shinyapps.io
rsconnect::deployApp()"
```

At this point any thoughts, ideas, or just points in the right direction would be great!

Comment: Is `rsconnect::deployApp()` in the code you're trying to deploy? Have you tried removing that and using the GUI in Rstudio instead? I'd also try removing the `dump` and reinstating `shinyApp()`

Comment: @smartse It is not, but just to make sure I removed both as per your suggestion and used shinyApp() to deploy and received the same errors.

Comment: `shinyApp()` runs the app, it doesn't deploy it anywhere, but it is needed in the version you deploy so that it runs once deployed. I was suggesting that you try to deploy using this method: https://docs.posit.co/shinyapps.io/getting-started.html#deploying-your-first-application i.e. once you have it running locally in Rstudio

Comment: Oh actually, I think I see the problem - `setCurrentTheme` is related to the session object but you are not passing that to to server: https://rdrr.io/cran/shiny/man/session.html so try `geo_server <- function(input, output,session)` instead

Comment: @smartse No change, same error :(. I am wondering if it might be on Shiny's end, my account, or some residual file that's not getting cleaned. Going to try again on a new account/another deployment system/new r instance and see if that helps. Please let me know if you think of any other ideas to try and thank you for your help so far!

Comment: Hmm that is puzzling. Maybe try deploying something very simple like https://mastering-shiny.org/basic-app.html#create-app first as that will confirm whether it is a problem with deploying vs something in your code